# Google Analytics v4 tracking screen stay time

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics v4(GA) to track each screen. How to check each screen stay time according to custom params "story_id"?

eg. I setup one custom params "story_id". When user redirect to story page in app, it will send set screen name event to GA include the "story_id" params.

In Pages and screens of GA Engagement, it will work to track each screen stay time. when i add params "story_id" to display each data, the each item will display 0m00s of Average Engagement Time but the not set "story_id" item time have Average Engagement Time.

How to subdivide the item data by params "story_id"?